# Dart - Know whether or not it is a test

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-test

When using Flutter, it is possible to define a variable

```dart
final isTest = Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST');
```

which will be `true` when using `flutter test` and `false` otherwise.

Is there an equivalent for when using `dart test`? I tried to inspect `Platform.environment` but didn't find anything specific to dart.

Comment: It still returns `false` as `'FLUTTER_TEST'` is not in the environment. I'm running `dart test` and not `flutter test`. Therefore, it is not using flutter

Comment: Volkswagen did this, and it led to some serious financial penalties and marketplace loss.  Only partially kidding that this would apply to you. Please don't have the code detect the test... just set it up to plug in dependency injection for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any direct way to detect if your code is running via `dart test`.  However, you generally should avoid writing such code.  Code that checks if it's being tested so that it can behave differently in a test guarantees that your test coverage will not execute the non-test code paths.  Instead, your code should be parameterized (perhaps with a formal dependency injection framework) so that the tests can supply mocks or fakes to the code being tested.

If your goal is to generate additional diagnostic output during tests, then test coverage won't be a problem.  However, in such a case you should be using something like [`package:logging`](https://pub.dev/packages/logging), unconditionally call logging functions, and have only your tests configure those logging functions to generate actual output.

But if you still really want to detect if your code is running via `dart test`, then an indirect way could be to check [`Platform.script`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/Platform/script.html) to see if your code is being executed by the test runner:

```dart
bool isRunByDartTestRunner() => Platform.script.contains('/dart_test.');
```

However, do note that the above isn't foolproof:

- It will report false positives if the code is executed by a script that happens to have `/dart_test.` in its path.
- It will work only with `dart test` and not for tests wrapped by some other testing framework.
- There's no guarantee that such a heuristic would continue working in the future.

And, of course, another option would be to simply have the code being tested provide some global `bool` variable, and then make your tests explicitly set it.

(If https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28160 ever gets addressed, then another option would be to have your tests explicitly set an environment variable themselves.)